# How can get current index name while adding a custom fields to a Solr schema in using 'IPopulateHelperFactory' Sitecore 10.3

Tags: sitecore-client, solr

I am adding custom fields in solr schema in Sitecore 10.3. But it will be for specific index.

How can i get index name in the class which is inherited from IPopulateHelperFactory [refer this link to add custom code](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/add-custom-fields-to-a-solr-schema.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index name is not passed OOTB to `SchemaPopulateHelper` class.

However there is a workaround using Sitecore `Switcher` class.

- First create a class that inherits from mentioned above `Switcher` class with `PopulateManagedSchemaArgs` type. This class does not need any method. It should be like:

```
public class PopulateManagedSchemaArgsSwitcher 
    : Switcher<Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.PopulateManagedSchemaArgs>
{
}
```

- Next create 2 classes implementing `PopulateManagedSchemaProcessor`, one that will enter the switcher with current `PopulateManagedSchemaArgs`, and one that will exit the switcher:

```
public class EnterPopulateManagedSchemaArgsSwitcher : PopulateManagedSchemaProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PopulateManagedSchemaArgs args)
    {
        PopulateManagedSchemaArgsSwitcher.Enter(args);
    }
}

public class ExitPopulateManagedSchemaArgsSwitcher : PopulateManagedSchemaProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PopulateManagedSchemaArgs args)
    {
        PopulateManagedSchemaArgsSwitcher.Exit();
    }
}
```

- Then create your `CustomPopulateHelper` class that will override default `SchemaPopulateHelper` class, and in the `GetAllFields` method it will read index and core names from the switcher:

```
public class CustomPopulateHelper : SchemaPopulateHelper
{
    public CustomPopulateHelper(SolrSchema solrSchema) : base(solrSchema)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<XElement> GetAllFields()
    {
        var args = PopulateManagedSchemaArgsSwitcher.CurrentValue;
        var indexName = args?.Index?.Name;
        var cores = args?.Cores?.ToList();

        var baseFields = base.GetAllFields().ToList();

        if (indexName == "my_custom_index")
        {
            baseFields.Add(CreateField("my_custom_field", "text_general", false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false));
        }

        return baseFields;
    }
}
```

From what I can see, there is always single core in `args.Cores` and that core name is equal to `args.Index.Name`. I'm sure there may be specific case when it will be different, but I'm not sure when and why.

- Now it's time for factory, that will create your `CustomPopulateHelper` instead of default one:

```
public class CustomPopulateHelperFactory : IPopulateHelperFactory
{
    public ISchemaPopulateHelper GetPopulateHelper(SolrSchema solrSchema)
    {
        return new CustomPopulateHelper(solrSchema);
    }
}
```

And the last thing is config file which binds everything together:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" search:require="solr">
    <pipelines>
      <contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.ResolveCoreNames, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <processor 
            type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.EnterPopulateManagedSchemaArgsSwitcher, MyAssembly"
            patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.PopulateFields, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider']">
          </processor>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.PopulateFields, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <param 
                type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.CustomPopulateHelperFactory, MyAssembly" 
                patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Factories.DefaultPopulateHelperFactory']"/>
        </processor>
        <processor
            type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.ExitPopulateManagedSchemaArgsSwitcher, MyAssembly"
            patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.PopulateFields, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider']">
        </processor>
      </contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

- And that's it, your custom field will be added to the `managed-schema` of the index:

[image]